# Setup Swagger UI on Jersey Grizzly

Tags: java, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-ui, grizzly

All the tutorials online say that you should place "dist" folder from Swagger UI under "WebContent" to get the Swagger UI working.

But what if I don't have "WebContent"?!

My Jersey-Jaxrs-RESTful application runs correctly on embedded Grizzly server.

I have Swagger correctly set up and when I go to `localhost:9998/swagger.json` I can see all the API documentation in JSON format. Now, all I want is the Swagger UI to show this JSON data in a nice HTML page.

My question is how can I set up this Swagger UI without a WebContent folder and web.xml file.

Here is my `index.html` JS configuration to start Swagger UI; the `url=http://localhost:9998/api/api-docs/swagger.json`

My Application configuration:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ResConfig extends Application {
public ResConfig() {
    super();
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] { "http" });
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost:9998");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("test.resources");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}


@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    resources.add(Res.class);

    resources.add(CrossDomainFilter.class);

    resources.add(io.swagger.jersey.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON.class);
    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
    return resources;
}
}


public class CrossDomainFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    public CrossDomainFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "");
    }
}
```

There was an open issue about this problem at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/958 ; however, it was not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting the static Swagger UI files? That would look something like this:

```
ClassLoader loader = Main.class.getClassLoader();
CLStaticHttpHandler docsHandler = new CLStaticHttpHandler(loader, "swagger/");
docsHandler.setFileCacheEnabled(false);

ServerConfiguration cfg = server.getServerConfiguration()
cfg.addHttpHandler(docsHandler, "/docs/");
```

Where the contents of the folder `swagger` will contain all the swagger UI stuff.

Grizzly currently has a bug with how it handles paths to static resources, so when you visit the docs, you need to ensure you have the trailing slash at the end. So, for example it might be `localhost:9998/docs/`